# How to change the seat clamp on a dropper post?

Tags: repair, seatpost, clamp

While trying to tighten the screws on the seat clamp on my wife's bike, I overtightened one of the screws, damaging both the screw and the seat clamp. (I had used a torque wrench and had set it to the recommended max torque of 3 Nm, but it didn't click/release on one of the screws for some reason - I'll be more careful next time...)

I now have a replacement seat clamp, but was wondering what the easiest way to replace the defective one was. The complexity is that the bike has a dropper seat post, which means that I'll have to pull the seat post out of the seat tube and then try to remove/reinstall the new clamp over the seat post cable. On my wife's bike, the cabling is routed internally in the frame.

Since the seat post remote's cable is already frayed out a bit at the end at the remote's end, I want to avoid removing the cable from the remote - I'm afraid that it will be difficult to get it back into the remote...

Is there an easy way to replace the seat clamp in this scenario? My current preferred way would be to unscrew the remote from the handle bar to give the cable enough slack for pulling the seat post out of the seat tube. Am I on the right track, or is there a better way?

[image: Dropper Post]

Comment: This post describes a similar problem, although not related to the seat clamp: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/how-easy-is-it-to-remove-a-seat-with-a-dropper-post

Comment: For the cost of a new cable inner, I would not spend more than a few minutes shagging around finding an alternate way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already noted you have to unscrew the remote from the handlebar and push the hose/cable into the frame so you can pull on the dropper post. Afterwards you just remove the screws from the seat clamp and pull it over the cable. Install everything backwards and you are good to go again.

Comment: Thanks for validating my approach - good to hear that I'm on the right track. I'll give this a try (unless there are other answers that propose a different approach) and will accept the answer if this approach worked :-)

Comment: I'm happy to report that this worked out fine and was pretty much painless.

Comment: Perfect, glad if I could help.